# Unable to get some website on Ubuntu after I use it for some time

Tags: internet, chromium, mozilla

I am unable to access most of websites after some usage. (happens only sometimes)
But sites like **Google** and **Facebook** are working perfectly. But most of the other sites like **GitHub**, **askubuntu** are not loading.
There is no problem with the Internet connection thouugh.

I tried to open these sites using Chromium but the problem continues.
But once I restart the system everything works fine.

Comment: Looks like a networking issue though it’s unclear at what level it occurs. What is Chromium’s observable behaviour when it can’t display the web pages in question? What’s the *exact* wording of its error message if any? Also, could you please run `export LC_MESSAGES=POSIX; ifconfig; ip -4 route; ip -6 route; host [site] || host [site] 8.8.8.8 && ping -c4 [site]` where `[site]` is the host name of one of the affected web pages, e. g. `github.com` or `askubuntu.com`, the next time they become unreachable? Thanks.

Comment: I think the issue may be the dns resolver. run `sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved`  to restart the resolver, if this solves it, the issue is probably systemd-resolved.

Comment: It would help if you provided actual error messages instead of just saying "not loading".